# PHP Session Array Values Lost On Third Page

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a long data information sheet which I have divided into three pages.
What I have been trying to do is to:

> 1. start a session on page 1 to carry over array $sda to page 2,
> 2. have a session on page 2 to carry over arrays $sda and $sdb data to page 3,
> 3. and on page 3, insert all array data to a database and end the session.

However, on page 3, array $sda from page 1 becomes null and only array $sdb is transferred. What am I failing to do?

Here is my code:
PAGE 1, user fills up the form, values are put into array $sda, user clicks submit

```
session_start();
 $_SESSION['sda'] = $sda;
 header("location:enrol.php?a=2");
```

PAGE 2

```
session_start();
 $sda = $_SESSION['sda'];
 print_r($_SESSION);
```

user fills up form, values are put into array $sdb, (values in array $sda SHOULD BE retained and passed on to page 3. it doesn't really need to be printed in this page but I did so to check whether I could access its contents from the previous page--which works just fine and prints

```
Array ( [sda] => Array ( [0] => First [1] => Mid [2] => Last [3] => Nick [4] => Cit [5] => Place [6] => January [7] => 1 [8] => 2012 [10] => Grade 1 [9] => School [11] => Home [12] => [13] => A@B.C [14] => [15] => [16] => Guard [17] => Rel [18] => 12345678 [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => [34] => [35] => [37] => [39] => [41] => [36] => [38] => [40] => ) [sdb] => Array ( [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => a [22] => b [23] => c [24] => d [25] => e [26] => f ) )
```

user clicks submit (I just want $sda values on the next page. Am I doing it right? :z)

```
session_start();
 $_SESSION['sda'] = $sda;
 $_SESSION['sdb'] = $sdb;
 header("location:enrol.php?a=3");
```

PAGE 3

```
session_start();
 $sda = $_SESSION['sda'];
 $sdb = $_SESSION['sdb'];
 print_r($_SESSION);
```

ERROR HERE! $SDA VALUES ARE LOST though $sdb values are printed;

```
Array ( [sda] => [sdb] => Array ( [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => a [22] => b [23] => c [24] => d [25] => e [26] => f ) )
```

on submit
save to database and destroy session

Comment: On submit means another page, right? There is no `$sda` array but you put into `$_SESSION['sda']`. That's why `$sda` is empty on page 3.

Comment: just make sure on page two, you don't overwrite the first container with an empty value.

Comment: Page 2 onsubmit why do you reset $_SESSION['sda'] = $sda; , is there any change in $_SESSION['sda'] ?

Comment: Please print $sda on page 2 onsubmit  just before  $sda = $_SESSION['sda']; i think $sda is inserting nothing

Comment: I see. I should remove  just $_SESSION['sda'] = $sda; on Page 2 submit. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from your code which is return after

```
 user clicks submit (I just want $sda values on the next page. Am I doing it right? :z)
```

i.e.

```
  $_SESSION['sda'] = $sda;
```